# How to group data by 6 month in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe and I want to get the sum of the Revenue per 6 month. I can extract quarter, month, year out of the date, but I am unable to do it for the 6 month

```
| date      | Revenue |
|-----------|---------|
| 1/2/2017  | 200     |
| 2/2/2017  | 300     |
| 3/2/2017  | 100     |
| 4/2/2017  | 100     |
| 5/23/2017 | 200     |
| 6/20/2017 | 300     |
| 7/22/2017 | 400     |
| 8/21/2017 | 800     |
| 9/21/2017 | 500     |
| 10/21/2017| 500     |
| 11/21/2017| 500     |
| 12/21/2017| 500     |
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a for loop with range (0,5)? You could also first make 2 arrays with both halves in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `resample`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.resample('6M', on='date').sum().reset_index()
#output
    date        renevue
0   2017-01-31  200
1   2017-07-31  1400
2   2018-01-31  2800
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dfg = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='6M')).sum().reset_index()

        date  Revenue
0 2017-01-31      200
1 2017-07-31     1400
2 2018-01-31     2800
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year_half'] = df.date.dt.month <= 6
df.groupby([df.year_half, df.date.dt.year])['Revenue'].sum()
```